# Set a range in Excel based on values of corresponding cells

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I have 2 columns in Excel, like this:

> Col1 Col2
>
> A     1
>
> B     2
>
> C     4
>
> C     1
>
> A     13
>
> B     5

I need to generate 3 ranges in excel containing the values in Col2 , based on the distinct values of Col1.
Thus:
Name Range **A** will have values **1,13**
Name Range **B** will have values **2,5**
Name Range **C** will have values **1,4**

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following formula in `Cell D2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$17, MATCH(0, IF(D$1=$A$2:$A$17, COUNTIF(D$1:D1, $B$2:$B$17), ""), 0)),"")
```

Drag/Copy down and across as required.

This is an **array formula** so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. See image for reference.

[image]

**EDIT:________________________________**

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$18, SMALL(IF(D$1=$A$2:$A$18, ROW($A$2:$A$18)-1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")
```

Again this is an array formula.

Comment: It returns only empty cells, i guess it is smth wrong with it

Comment: @Andrei - This is an array formula so you'll have to press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` instead of just `Enter`.

Comment: @Andrei - And `A, B, C` should be entered in Cells `D1, E1, F1` respectively for formula to work.

Comment: if there are duplicates in Col 2 the formula does not work as it only shows the values once. I need them as many times as they appear

Comment: @Andrei - Oh. I took `based on the distinct values of Col1` as unique values. Will edit my answer.

Comment: i am looking for the formula to be placed in a Named range thus returning an array.

Comment: It works only by eliminating -1 from ROW($A$2:$A$18)-1. is there a way to have an array returned and placed in a Named Range instead of using cell based formula ?

Comment: @Andrei - To return array you'll have to use VBA. To my knowledge its not possible using formula.